# Looking for simple cropbox 'how to save' or update

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have this from the jsfiddle:

```
$(function () {

    var r = $('#results'),
        x = $('.cropX', r),
        y = $('.cropY', r),
        w = $('.cropW', r),
        h = $('.cropH', r);
    $('.cropbox').cropbox({
        width: 920,
        height: 356
    }).on('cropbox', function (event, results, img) {
        var crop = $('.cropbox').data('cropbox');
        x.text(results.cropX);
        y.text(results.cropY);
        w.text(results.cropW);
        h.text(results.cropH);
        console.log(crop.result);
        //alert(event);
    });
});
```

also from the developers site there are methods I do not know how to implement:

update  (none)  Update the cropped result (must call after zoom and drag).

getDataURL  (none)  Generate a URL for the cropped image on the client (requires HTML5 compliant browser).

I need to save the cropped image to the server it was just uploaded to

Any thoughts/ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/acornejo/jquery-cropbox/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Hi I guess no body have answered properly this question in you code:

```
$('.cropbox').cropbox({
    width: 920,
    height: 356
}).on('cropbox', function (event, results, img) {

});
```

after where you declare `width` and `height` you can add another parameter which is a function callback. and is fired when the `on crop` event is finish.

so you can do this.

```
$('.cropbox').cropbox({
    width: 920,
    height: 356
}, function(){ 
   //this is the callback
   //now you can do
   this.getBlob();
   this.getDataURL(); 
}).on('cropbox', function (event, results, img) {

});
```

actually this is explained in the documentation. but if somebody missed this is the answer.

Answer (score -1):

use 
`img.getBlob();`  or `img.getDataURL()` for cropped image and send the data to server